# Process exits on terminal session end, even though it's a background process

Tags: process, background-process

I connect to my VPS using ssh. I run `npm run start &` to start my next.js site in the background. And everything works.

As soon as I disconnect my SSH session, my site stops.

How can I force that process to stay alive?

Answer (score 1):

It is normal that all processes started in the background are terminated as soon as the shell in which they were started terminates. They all receive a SIGHUP signal when you quit the session.

`nohup` can be used to launch the process disconnected from the terminal session, but also from stdin and stdout, and immune to a SIGHUP signal from the terminal. Output of the process will be redirected to a file `nohup.out`.

You can also use a terminal multiplexer like GNU screen or tmux on the server side. A multiplexer allows you to "detach" a terminal, so the processes are left running even when you quit the SSH connection. When reconnecting, you can reattach to continue working.